# Can I upgrade Ubuntu from a Windows burnt disc?

Tags: windows, updates, burning

I currently have Ubuntu 10 (Or 11) on my laptop but no Internet access so I can't use Update Manager. I want to burn a disc from (this) Windows computer to take home for the upgrade. Will this be exactly the same process as burning and installing straight from Windows? The instructions clearly state that to burn a disc from Windows is to install from Windows, no actual burn disc from Windows and update previous Ubuntu OS instruction.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a disk (whether burnt on a DVD or on a USB stick), it's a bootable disk that you can use from start-up whether the computer in question has Windows, Ubuntu, both, another OS entirely, or has been completely screwed up by an interesting experiment and no longer has any OS on it at all (which is just as well for some of us).

The lack of an internet connection would of course prevent you from updating what you have, or installing anything that isn't included in the ISO. It might be better to take the laptop to the connection, than the Ubuntu to the laptop.

Still, a disk burnt from within Windows does not require Windows to be on the target machine.